# MySQL - ListMenus/Comboboxes

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, combobox, listbox

I am trying to build a dynamic set of comboboxes/listMenus getting data from a MySQL DB.  My database has 5 fields, 1st being id and

topic, sub_topic, info and url

I want to make it so that until user selects a valid choice from box1 that the others are disabled.  Once user selects from box 1 box 2 will be activated.  Once you make a selection from box 2 then the info and url will be shown.

I have followed a tutorial http://www.ssdtutorials.com/tutorials/series/dependable-dropdown.html and so most of this code is not mine apart from the SELECT statements

I am having problems writing the MySQL for update.php as this populates the other boxes (currently I am sticking with the comboboxes until I have it working.)

I would be grateful for some help, due to the amount of code it can be seen here http://pastebin.com/QNbHR9JK

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I see is that in update.php query, you aren't actually using a where clause. When you execute the prepared query, you pass in a value array, but there aren't any placeholders in the prepared query.

I would expect something like:

```
$sql = "SELECT `topic`,`sub_topic`,`info`,`url`
                    FROM `links` WHERE sub_topic=?";
            $statement = $objDb->prepare($sql);
            $statement->execute(array($value));
```

One other thing I notice is that in your foreach in update.php, you are using $row['id'] but you aren't selecting that column in your query.

**EDIT**

I updated the query to use the proper column in where clause, and removed to group by clause based on discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the statement.  As far as the id this is still the original code, I am trying to convert it so that it picks up the corresponding field/data.  Would I be better to include id in the select field for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, I would add `id` to the select statement. Also, just FYI, you need to make sure that you change `value` in the where clause to the proper field that you need to look in.

Comment: So far in update.php I have $sql = "SELECT `id`,`topic`,`sub_topic`,`info`,`url`
                    FROM `links` WHERE sub_topic = ? GROUP BY `topic`";   sub_topic being the 2nd level box that should enable once the first box choice has been made but so far it is failing. Is this failing purely because I do not have the WHERE part of the statement exactly right?

Comment: Granted, I don't know what your data looks like, but do you need the `GROUP BY` clause for this query? If you have multiple rows for a sub_topic that have the same topic, you will only ever get the row for one of them.

Comment: What do you mean by 'failing'? Is it throwing an error, or is it not giving you the results you expect?

Comment: I used the group by because the topic has multiples of the same in the db.  The records I have in topics so far are multiples of web design, hardware etc etc so in the first box I only want 1 of each item listed, thought this was best way to do that?

Comment: That is what you need for the first query. However, for the query to populate the second box, you don't want to group by because you want every record for the topic selected i.e. if web design is selected in the first box, you want every sub_topic for the web design topic in the second box.

Comment: So the update.php query should be "SELECT `id`,`topic`,`sub_topic`,`info`,`url`
                    FROM `links` WHERE sub_topic = ?"; ?

Comment: To your earlier question abt whether throwing an error or not giving expected results.  Box1 is populating but 2 is not being activated so i assume not being populated.

Comment: If it is any use for you to see the DB see here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3833032/links.sql

Comment: I'd call update.php from the browser or use Firebug or Chrome Dev tools to see what is being returned/echoed by your update.php script. You need to make sure it is generating the option list that you expect. If it is, then you need to look at your javascript that is populating the dropdown.

Comment: Used chrome dev tools, after making selection from top box there was no output shown.

Comment: Call directly from the browser: localhost/update.php?id=1&value=Web%20Development (or whatever your values are) to make sure that the script is generating the expected output.

Comment: I corrected a typo and now am getting the top box return the values stored but it is not returning anything for 2nd level box

Comment: Using the dev tools for the tutorial to see roughly what I should get back from the browser I first checked the tutorial I had completed, [swf link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3833032/dropdowns/dropdowns.html).  I then tested my dropdowns and all I get is [swf link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3833032/dropdowns/mydropdowns/mydropdowns.html).  I have gone through the code in update.php, index.php and the JS and connaot see why the 2nd box is not populating.  I apprreciate your help by the way, thanks.

Comment: I have started to make headway, I have altered the SELECT statement to $sql = "SELECT `id`, `sub_topic`
                    FROM `links` WHERE id = ?"; this gives me the following output [link swf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3833032/dropdowns/dropdowns2/dropdownproject2.html) as you see I only get 1 record in the second box but at least it is being enabled and something is going in there now.  Just need to work on the statement to get all the sub_topics from the db now.  Rather than WHERE id = I am thinking maybe I should remove from WHERE onwards?  any suggestions?

Comment: I am now getting box 2 to populate but my SELECT statement is not quite right, I am getting all sub topics listed no matter which choice made from selection box 1.  $sql = "SELECT `id`, `sub_topic`, `url`, `info`
                    FROM `links`";

Comment: Did you ever verify that your update.php script is returning multiple options? One of two things is happening. Either update.php is only returning one row from the query, or the javascript isn't properly adding the options to the dropdown. Also, can you post your modified code so I can see it?

Comment: You're getting all the rows because by removing the WHERE, you are returning every row in your table.

Comment: but when I used the where I was not getting any data as well as the dropdown was still disabled, I know I need the where, but cannot work out how to get to the correct statement. As well as this proving to me that it is the statement that is the problem rather than the other files.  [My updated code] (http://pastebin.com/QNbHR9JK)

Comment: Ok. You need different queries for the second and third boxes. For the second box you need `SELECT DISTINCT(sub_topic) FROM links WHERE topic=$option1Value` to get the options for the third dropdown, you need `SELECT id,topic,sub_topic,info,url FROM links WHERE sub_topic=$option2Value` For the second dropdown query, you only need the distinct sub_topics, and you don't need the id.

Comment: I just tried the first change, SELECT DISTINCT(sub_topic) FROM links WHERE topic=$option1Value when I made a selection from box1, box2 stayed disabled.

Comment: You need to change `$option1Value` to be whatever variable you are using to hold the submitted value. I just used that as a place holder.

Comment: The only statement that returned anything is SELECT DISTINCT(sub_topic) FROM links WHERE topic=$id but that still returns all sub_topics records outside of the topic selected.

Comment: I still think you are using the wrong variable. Lets say that in the first dropdown I selected 'Web Design'. You'd need the query run to be `SELECT DISTINCT(sub_topic) FROM links WHERE topic='Web Design'`. According to the sql dump you gave, that would give you 36 distinct options (there are 42 total entries in this topic). You'd then select one of these distinct options in the 2nd dropdown to get a list of all the links for that subtopic. I think you are actually attempting to use the numeric id number which isn't what you want.

Comment: As a test I entered your last example, using hardware, there are 2 entries in the DB but due to the Distinct I get 1 entry so yes now I see what you are saying but I have gone through all the variables used in the form but nothing seems to return anything bar the $id which although returns data its all records not just the sub_topics.  I have currently removed DISTINCT from the sub_topic statement as even though there are duplicates, i.e hardware has 2 keyboards as sub_topics by clicking on 1 or the other will produce info and url.

Comment: In your index.php file, where you generate your first dropdown, change it so that it is `<option value='$row['topic']'>$row['topic']</option>`. In your jQuery, you are setting $_GET['value'] to the value of the dropdown. That is the value that you need to use for the WHERE. So it needs to be `FROM links WHERE topic='$value'`

Comment: Thank you very much.  That seems to have done the trick, I did try value b4 but in index I had id and topic.  Well hopefully from the help you have given me I will be able to get the third one working.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're quite welcome. Feel free to throw an upvote and/or accept my way :)

Comment: Tried to vote up but getting message saying I need a +15 rep ?